# Assign ranks based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have identified some duplicates in my data (based on V1,V2,V3,V4), however as it is getting difficult to manually review too many records, I would like to assign ranks based on a few conditions:

1. if V5,V6 match - rank -1
2. if V7,V8 match - rank -2

and so on. how can this be achieved?

T1

```
ID |   V1 |  V2 |  V5   | V6 | CreatedDate   
---| ---  | ---    ---   --- ----------  
1  |   A  |  US |  1984 | QR | 01-AUG-2017  
2  |   B  |  FR |  1991 | TY | 01-JAN-2017  
3  |   C  |  AU |  1989 | GH | 25-SEP-2017  
4  |   B  |  FR |  1995 | BN | 01-AUG-2017  
5  |   A  |  US |  1984 | QR | 30-MAR-2016  
6  |   C  |  AU |  1999 | MK | 14-JUN-2015
```

T2

```
ID | V3    | V7    
---| ---    ---                
1  | Apple   D12    
1  | Kiwi    S45    
2  | Pear    T23           
3  | Banana  U78           
4  | Pear    T23    
5  | Apple   D12    
6  | Banana  P90
```

T3

```
ID | V4      V8    
---|  ---    ---    
1  | Spinach A678    
1  | Beets   V902    
2  | Celery  T456    
3  | Radish  Y675    
4  | Celery  T456    
5  | Spinach G890     
6  | Celery  F567    
6  | Radish  R453


1 A US Apple Spinach 1984 QR D12 A678 1    
5 A US Apple Spinach 1984 QR D12 G890 1    
2 B FR Pear  Celery  1991 TY T23 T456 2     
4 B FR Pear  Celery  1995 BN T23 T456 2
```

Comment: How are the table joined? Because why `1` have `Apple` but not `Kiwi` Have `Spinach` and  not `Beets`?     Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your basic problem is just regarding T1. T2 and T3 is just additional information.

So because your example data isnt clear I will focus only on T1.

Here you join T1 with itself and see if exist same value on the columns.

```
SELECT TA.*, TB.*,
       CASE WHEN TA.V5 = TB.V5  AND TA.V6 = TB.V6
            THEN 'rank -1'
            WHEN TA.V7 = TB.V7  AND TA.V8 = TB.V7
            THEN 'rank -2'
       END as ranking
FROM T1 as TA
JOIN T1 as TB
  ON TA.ID < TB.ID
 AND (  (TA.V5 = TB.V5  AND TA.V6 = TB.V6)
     OR (TA.V7 = TB.V7  AND TA.V8 = TB.V7)
     )
```

Comment: T3 is not additional info because I am determining the duplicates based on all 4 values - V1, V2,V3 and V4 (which is in T3), I have already identified dups but I want to now know how I can assign ranking.

Comment: Again I did what I could with the info. Im not sure how you join because you dont show enough sample.